# React context - 'contextType' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am using react-dom@16.6.1 and react@16.6.1 that should support react `Context` and trying to run a simple example same as the [react-context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppManger from './components/AppManger';
import './App.css';
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({a1:'a1'});

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="App">
        <h1>Manage Storefront Services Products</h1>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
          <AppManger />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

AppManger.js(has no context reference)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
export default class AppManger extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSearchBarChange = this.onSearchBarChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            searchValue: '',
            errorLoading: false,
            errorObj: null,
        }
    }

    onSearchBarChange(e) {
        e.persist();
        this.setState({ searchValue: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <a href="/subsadmin/saml/logout">Log out</a>
                <SearchBar onSearchBarChange={this.onSearchBarChange} inAttrView={this.state.onAttrPage} />
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

And the SearchBar.js where I want to use Context:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ThemeContext from '../App';


export default class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      showAttrModal: false
    };

  };


  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.context); //{}
  }

  render() {
    const contextType = ThemeContext;
    console.log(contextType); //{}
    return (

      <div>
        {contextType} /*'contextType' is not defined  no-undef */
        <input type="text" style={searchBoxStyle} className="form-control" onChange={this.props.onSearchBarChange} placeholder="Search for..." id="sku" name="sku" />

      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

If I run the app I get   `Line 44:  'contextType' is not defined no-undef` in SearchBar.js if I remove this line I get `{}` when I logging the `this.context`.

Comment: I guess it's should be `const contextType = ThemeContext`

Comment: Yes, but it still shows `{}` instead of real value.

Comment: Your `ThemeContext` is a component or a value?

Comment: a value defined like -`export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({a1:'a1'});` in App.js

Comment: Please try this `import { ThemeContext } from '../App'`

Comment: already Did it in SearchBar.js - `import ThemeContext from '../App';`

Comment: No I mean `{ ThemeContext }` not `ThemeContext`.

Comment: Because `import foo from bar` mean use `export default foo`

Comment: If you have multiple export and it's const. You must use `{ foo }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't correctly using context, as you need to define it as a static property of the class and import it as a named import since you have exported it as a named import

```
import { ThemeContext } from '../App';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      showAttrModal: false
    };

  };

  static contextType = ThemeContext;
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.context); //{}
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.contextType); //{}
    return (

      <div>
        {contextType} /*'contextType' is not defined  no-undef */
        <input type="text" style={searchBoxStyle} className="form-control" onChange={this.props.onSearchBarChange} placeholder="Search for..." id="sku" name="sku" />

      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Works but to access the context I logged `ThemeContext` instead. Thank`s.

Comment: You can use ThemeContext but for some reason if you have a PureComponent in between the Provider and Consumer then I guess the re-render won't  be triggered on context change

Answer (score 3):

You imported `App` instead of `ThemeContext`.

use `import { ThemeContext } from '../App.js`;

Comment: Still the same result `{}`.

Comment: Did you you `static contextType = ThemeContext; `?

Answer (score -1):

Here problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context);
}
```

Here can't find `this.context` variable.

```
static contextType = 

To

const contextType =
```