# React Context not working: is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

How come my Context is not working in React? Receiving an undefined error below.

```
import React, { useContext }  from 'react';

function BookList() {
  const PrintContext = React.createContext("CAR");

  const list = [
    { title: 'ABCDE', author: 'John Smith' }
  ]

  return (
    <PrintContext.Provider value="APPLE">
    <ul>
      {list.map((book, i) => <Book title={book.title} author={book.author} key={i} />)}
    </ul>
    </PrintContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Book(props) {
  const theme = useContext(PrintContext)
  return (
    <li>
      <h2>{theme}</h2>
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <div>{props.author}</div>
      <input value={props.year} />
    </li>
  )
}
```

**Receiving Error:**

> 'PrintContext' is not defined  no-undef

using latest version of React

**Resource:**

[React context - 'contextType' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924140/react-context-contexttype-is-not-defined)

Comment: hi @PrãtéékThápá it works, feel free to place in answer, and I can send points, thanks !

Comment: Normal JavaScript shopping still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your PrintContext outside the scope of `Booklist` function.

```
import React, { useContext }  from 'react';

const PrintContext = React.createContext("CAR");

function BookList() {

  const list = [
    { title: 'ABCDE', author: 'John Smith' }
  ]

  return (
    <PrintContext.Provider value="APPLE">
    <ul>
      {list.map((book, i) => <Book title={book.title} author={book.author} key={i} />)}
    </ul>
    </PrintContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Book(props) {
  const theme = useContext(PrintContext)
  return (
    <li>
      <h2>{theme}</h2>
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <div>{props.author}</div>
      <input value={props.year} />
    </li>
  )
}
```